# How to convert one word to other forms of it by using StanfordNLP

Tags: nlp, cpu-word, stanford-nlp

i want to convert words between verb/noun/adjective forms with stanford nlp

For example , ntlk supply functions

```
    print verbify('writer') # => ['write']
print nounize('written') # => ['writer']
print adjectivate('write') # => ['written']
```

i am looking for stanfordnlp functions version look like ntlk functions.

thank you
best regards

Comment: neither `NLTK` or stanford `CoreNLP` have the functions you listed. most probably you meant http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern

Comment: i develop our project with java . so i am looking for java solution. Do you know any page example contains functions of corenlp? Does clip.ua.ac.be/pattern use pyhton? Has it contains solution for other languages ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such documented functions in any of the Stanford NLP supported software distributions, but there is a work around offered in response to the question previously being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748787/convert-words-into-their-noun-adjective-verb-form-in-java)

Comment: does this work around solution been used with stanfordnlp ? or this is suitable for ntlk