# Find the base Verbs from derived NOUN forms

Tags: python, nlp

How can I find the base (root) form of Verbs from derived NOUN forms? Here are some examples that I'm looking for. Is there any dictionary I can use?

- Collection --> Collect
- Maintenance --> Maintain
- Replacement --> Replace

Comment: Related questions: [Convert words between verb/noun/adjective forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489309/convert-words-between-verb-noun-adjective-forms/16752477) & [Getting the closest noun from a stemmed word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083442/getting-the-closest-noun-from-a-stemmed-word). Also you could try [this aproach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18694016/4146962) using wordnet and nltk.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of a tool/dictionary that gets this automatically (i.e. verbs derived from nouns), but I guess you can derive some simple heuristics from something like this:
https://lexsrv2.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/2015/docs/designDoc/UDF/derivations/suffixList.html