# Getting adjective from an adverb in nltk or other NLP library

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Is there a way to get an adjective corresponding to a given adverb in NLTK or other python library.
For example, for the adverb "**terribly**", I need to get "**terrible**".
Thanks.

Comment: Try taking a look at this post:
[Convert words between verb/noun/adjective forms][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489309/convert-words-between-verb-noun-adjective-forms/16752477#16752477

Comment: @George-Bogdan Ivanov. Thanks, I tried it, but it didn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a relation in wordnet that connects the `adjectives` to `adverbs` and vice versa.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> from difflib import get_close_matches as gcm
>>> possible_adjectives = [k.name for k in chain(*[j.pertainyms() for j in chain(*[i.lemmas for i in wn.synsets('terribly')])])]
['terrible', 'atrocious', 'awful', 'rotten']
>>> gcm('terribly',possible_adjectives)
['terrible']
```

A more human readable way to compute`possible_adjective` is as followed:

```
possible_adj = []
for ss in wn.synsets('terribly'):
  for lemmas in ss.lemmas: # all possible lemmas.
    for lemma in lemmas: 
      for ps in lemma.pertainyms(): # all possible pertainyms.
        for p in ps:
          for ln in p.name: # all possible lemma names.
            possible_adj.append(ln)
```

EDIT: In the newer version of NLTK:

```
possible_adj = []
for ss in wn.synsets('terribly'):
  for lemmas in ss.lemmas(): # all possible lemmas
      for ps in lemmas.pertainyms(): # all possible pertainyms
          possible_adj.append(ps.name())
```

Comment: you will run into multiple answers from the code above but you could simply use the `list[0]` as the best answer.

Comment: in newer version of nltk , lemmas in now a method not an attribute

Comment: For me, it failed to transform 350 adverbs out of ~600.

Answer (score 1):

As MKoosej mentioned, nltk's lemmas is no longer an attribute but a method. I also made a little simplification to get the most possible word. Hope someone else can use it also:

```
wordtoinv = 'unduly'
s = []
winner = ""
for ss in wn.synsets(wordtoinv):
    for lemmas in ss.lemmas(): # all possible lemmas.
        s.append(lemmas)

for pers in s:
    posword = pers.pertainyms()[0].name()
    if posword[0:3] == wordtoinv[0:3]:
        winner = posword
        break

print winner # undue
```

Comment: please test the code before posting. This fails for the word that op asked: `terribly`

Comment: Should add "if len(pers.pertainyms())==0: continue". Is there a way to get from adjective to adverb?