# wordnet lemmatizer in NLTK is not working for adverbs

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
x = WordNetLemmatizer()   
x.lemmatize("angrily", pos='r')
Out[41]: 'angrily'
```

Here is reference documnetation for pos tags in nltk wordnet, http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html

I may be missing some basic things. Please let me know

Comment: should I delete this question OR let it be here just for people like me who searched web keeping "lemmatization" in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synset('angrily.r.1').lemmas()[0].pertainyms()[0].name()
u'angry'
```

See [Getting adjective from an adverb in nltk or other NLP library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245123/getting-adjective-from-an-adverb-in-nltk-or-other-nlp-library) for more information

The question is why do you have to go through the lemmas to get the pertainyms?

```
>>> wn.synset('angrily.r.1').pertainyms()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Synset' object has no attribute 'pertainyms'
```

It's because WordNet sees it as a lexical association between word categories, see http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wngloss.7WN.html

> Pertainyms are relational adjectives and do not follow the structure
>   just described. Pertainyms do not have antonyms; the synset for a
>   pertainym most often contains only one word or collocation and a
>   lexical pointer to the noun that the adjective is "pertaining to".
>   Participial adjectives have lexical pointers to the verbs that they
>   are derived from.

Then again, if we look at the Java interface, getting a synset's pertainym is as easy as `AdjectiveSynset.getPertainyms()` (http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/doc/edu/smu/tspell/wordnet/AdjectiveSynset.html)

So I guess it depends on who writes the interface, what sort of perspective they take towards adjective-adverb relationship.

For me I think pertainyms would have been directly related to the synset rather than the lemma.