# Nominalisation using nltk

Tags: python, nltk

My task is to convert any verb into appropriate noun form.

eg: improve - improvement
     recognize - recognition

etc ...

I tried this but I am getting an error

**my code :**

```
import nltk.app.wordnet_app as nwapp
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

word = "recognize"
print("Nominalizing " + word)
verb_synsets = wn.synsets(word, pos=wn.VERB)
print nwapp.get_relations_data(word,verb_synsets)
```

**my error :**

```
Nominalizing recognize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nominalizeme.py", line 8, in <module>
    print nwapp.get_relations_data(word,
verb_synsets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/app/wordnet_app.py", line 412, in get_relations_data
    if synset.pos == wn.NOUN:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'pos'
```

Comment: You need to loop over the items in the list of synsets?

Comment: I cannot understand can you please give me the fix

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489309/convert-words-between-verb-noun-adjective-forms/16752477#16752477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_relations_data()` takes one synset at a time. Your `verb_synsets` is a list of synsets, see http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/app/wordnet_app.html

```
>>> import nltk.app.wordnet_app as wnapp
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> word = "recognize"
>>> verb_synsets = wn.synsets(word, pos=wn.VERB)
>>> verb_synsets
[Synset('acknowledge.v.06'), Synset('recognize.v.02'), Synset('spot.v.02'), Synset('recognize.v.04'), Synset('accredit.v.01'), Synset('greet.v.01'), Synset('acknowledge.v.04'), Synset('recognize.v.08'), Synset('recognize.v.09')]
>>> print wnapp.get_relations_data(word, verb_synsets[0])
((18, 'Antonym', []), (0, 'Hyponym', []), (1, 'Direct hypernyms', [Synset('accept.v.01')]), (26, 'Indirect hypernyms', [(Synset('accept.v.01'), [(Synset('evaluate.v.02'), [(Synset('think.v.03'), [])])])]), (17, 'Entailments', []), (14, 'Causes', []), (15, 'Also see', []), (10, 'Verb Groups', []), (25, 'Derivationally related form', []))
```

Comment: can i get only derivationally related form

Comment: what do you mean by derivationally related form? I think you can try posting a new question too =)

Comment: you are right it worked, but this is not a bug ,you imported "import nltk.app.wordnet_app as wnapp" so it should be "wnapp.get_relations_data(word, verb_synsets[0])"