# How to I get related, but different POS word using nltk

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet

for example, I want to get word "india"(NOUN) from "indian"(ADJ).

I can find india from indian using wordnet browser but I don't know how to implement with python using nltk.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489309/convert-words-between-verb-noun-adjective-forms/16752477#16752477

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
syns = wn.synset('indian.a.01')  
print syns.lemmas[0].derivationally_related_forms()
print syns.lemmas[0].derivationally_related_forms()[0].name
```

You get:

`[Lemma('india.n.01.India')]
India`