# How to convert a verb to its (derived) noun form?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am working on a project related to NLP, in which I would like to identify main verb (I can do that with a dependency parser) from a sentence and then convert the verb to its noun form (or we can say noun derived from verb), for example `define to definition` or `sensitive to sensitivity` whenever possible. Are there any resources similar to wordnet or verbnet that provides this?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489309/convert-words-between-verb-noun-adjective-forms/16752477#16752477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start exploring the following resources:

1. [Morphosemantic Database](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/standoff/) from WordNet.

The Excel file contains entries like:

```
define%2:42:03::    202736778   result  definition%1:07:00::    104702957   show the form or outline of; "The tree w... clarity of outline; "exercise had given ...
```

2. [CatVar](http://clipdemos.umiacs.umd.edu/catvar/)

> A Categorial-Variation Database (or Catvar) is a database of clusters of uninflected words (lexemes) and their categorial (i.e. part-of-speech) variants. For example, the words hunger(V), hunger(N), hungry(AJ) and hungriness(N) are different English variants of some underlying concept describing the state of being hungry. Another example is the developing cluster:(develop(V), developer(N), developed(AJ), developing(N), developing(AJ), development(N)).

3. WordNet's word derivation relationship