# Get corresponding verbs and nouns for adverbs and adjectives

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

How can I get corresponding verbs and nouns for adverbs and adjectives in python? It seems simple succession and precedence may not be very accurate. There may be stopwords like to  eg. in I am delighted to learn...

I can't any library or even problem statement formalised as such.

Code right now. Now I want to return the corresponding the verb for adverb and noun for each adjective in the sentence.
Please help.

```
Code:
def pos_func(input_text):
    #pos tagging code:
    text=input_text
    tokens=tokenize_words(text)
    tagged=pos_tag(tokens)
    pos_store(tagged)

def pos_store(tagged):
    verbs=[]
    adjectives=[]
    adverbs=[]
    nouns=[]
    for tag in tagged:
        pos=tag[1]
        if pos[0]=='V':
            verbs.append(tag[0])
        elif pos[0]=='N':
            nouns.append(tag[0])
        elif pos[0]=='J':
            adjectives.append(tag[0])
        elif pos[0:2]=='RB':
            adverbs.append(tag[0])


def tokenize_words(text):
    tokens = TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(text)
    contractions = ["n't", "'ll", "'m"]
    fix = []
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        for c in contractions:
            if tokens[i] == c: fix.append(i)
    fix_offset = 0
    for fix_id in fix:
        idx = fix_id - 1 - fix_offset
        tokens[idx] = tokens[idx] + tokens[idx+1]
        del tokens[idx+1]
        fix_offset += 1
    return tokens
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. If your question is how to convert an adjective to the corresponding noun this might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489309/convert-words-between-verb-noun-adjective-forms/16752477#16752477 . You can also checkout this blog post for a more thorough explanation: http://tech.swamps.io/convert-words-between-verbnounadjectiveadverb-forms-using-wordnet/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I trying to solve a different problem. I want to pass the sentence and word (adjective) and get the corresponding the noun which the adjective describes in that everywhere sentence. Does this make some sense?

Comment: Considering the sentence: "delighted to learn", you what to extract ("delighted", "learn") ?

Comment: Yes, exactly as pairs!

Answer (score 7):

The general problem you are trying to solve is called **Dependency Parsing**. To extract such relations between words you need more then just the linear sequence of words that a simple POS tagging analysis offers. Consider the following sentence:

"He bought a beautiful and fast car." You would extract (beautiful, car) and (fast, car). You face a greater problem than just filtering stop words between a Noun and an Adverb. Using a parse tree analysis will give you a better idea of why this is not something you can solve using the word sequence.

This is the parse tree for our sentence:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP He))
    (VP (VBD bought)
      (NP (DT a)
        (ADJP (JJ beautiful)
          (CC and)
          (JJ fast))
        (NN car)))
    (. .)))
```

As you can see "a beautiful and fast car" is a NounPhrase (NP) containing a Determiner(DT), and AdjectivalPhrase(ADJP, "beautiful and fast") and Noun(NN, "car"). One approach that was used for some time was to create a rule based system that extracted the pairs from this parse tree. Fortunately, something even better has been developed that addresses your problem directly.

[image: DependencyGraph]

The dependency pairs are:

```
nsubj(bought-2, He-1)
root(ROOT-0, bought-2)
det(car-7, a-3)
amod(car-7, beautiful-4)
cc(beautiful-4, and-5)
conj:and(beautiful-4, fast-6)
amod(car-7, fast-6)
dobj(bought-2, car-7)
```

As you can see this is exactly what you need. These are typed dependencies, so you'll also need to filter the ones you are interested in(*amod*, *advmod* in your case)

You can find the full list of dependency types here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf
Stanford Parser Demo here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/
Stanford Core NLP Demo(for the cool visualisations) here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/

You can read a great article about creating a dependency parser in Python here (you will need training data though): https://honnibal.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/a-simple-fast-algorithm-for-natural-language-dependency-parsing/

Python interface to CoreNLP: https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python

You can also try writing your own dependency grammar, NLTK offers an API for that (look for chapter *"5   Dependencies and Dependency Grammar"*): http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

Answer (score 2):

Using the SpaCy library, and the sample sentence in [bogs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372693/6015216), I get something close to Stanford.

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
>>> doc = nlp("He bought a beautiful and fast car.")
# to match the output style of the Stanford library for comparison...
>>> for token in doc:
        print(f"{token.dep_}({token.head.text}-{token.head.i+1}, {token.text}-{token.i+1})")

nsubj(bought-2, He-1)
ROOT(bought-2, bought-2)
det(car-7, a-3)
amod(car-7, beautiful-4)
cc(beautiful-4, and-5)
conj(beautiful-4, fast-6)
dobj(bought-2, car-7)
punct(bought-2, .-8)
```

Interestingly, it misses the direct `amod` connection with the car being fast.

```
displacy.render(doc, style="dep", jupyter=True, options={'distance': 100})
```

[image]