# Implementing adjective-to-noun conversion across a wide swatch of words

Tags: javascript, performance, data-conversion

Looking for answers regarding converting adjectives into nouns in code. e.g., automagically using `foo._state.universal` to create a method `foo.getUniversality()`. Programming language is irrelevant, but here's an example end state in JavaScript:

```
import {getNounConversionOf} from '@servicenow/adjectivity';
getNounConversionOf('universal'); // => 'universality'
getNounConversionOf('order');     // => 'order'
getNounConversionOf('voracious'); // => 'voraciousness'
```

In English we use suffixes to express state/condition/quality. Examples for adjectives include -ity & -ness. Some words remain sans suffix regardless of state...
What’s are some efficient ways to implement a Node.js module that can accept an adjective & return its (potentially suffixed) noun form? [pluralize](https://github.com/plurals/pluralize/blob/master/pluralize.js#L273) uses an inline collection of tuples, e.g. `[/* Pronouns */['I', 'we'],...]`. Is there potentially a better way, & if not, do you know of a solid resource for getting everything that’d be in those tuples?

Comment: Example answers could include links to repositories of adjective-noun-suffix mappings

Comment: I found an implementation of this [in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218093/975097) using NLTK, but not in JavaScript.